# Filter unique items from one column to another in excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

There are two columns in excel 2013. column 'A' has  80 music name rows and another column 'B' has 50 similar music name records. I need to extract 30 unique music name records from column 'A' which has not similar from column 'B'. I tried with VLOOKUP but its not giving unique results.

Comment: do you mean the music names present in col A but not in col B?  A-B ?

Comment: Extract out 30 col A music names which does not matched with col B.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following formula in `Cell C2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$15,$B$2:$B$9,0),COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A$2:$A$15)),0)),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required. Change ranges in the formula as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `Column C`,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1),"",A1)
```

And drag it below for the 80 row range.